# Filling available space in set of slide toggles

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 2 `div`s with content that uses `JQuery` slidetoggle to show/hide, but I want the second to occupy all the remaining vertical height of the screen.

```
$('.heading').click(function (e) {
    $(e.target).parent().children('.content').slideToggle("fast", "swing");
});
```

jsFiddle I started: http://jsfiddle.net/LMHgM/

Any ideas how this can be done without resorting to javascript? Hopefully this should be browser resizing and other element resizing should keep this greedy `div` in the correct state. Currently my only solution has been to trigger my own resize method on slidetoggle and browser resize to correct the height.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the height as `100%` to the element and also to the `body` and `html`

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/LMHgM/3/

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
}

#second {
    border: 1px dashed blue;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Can we avoid the scroll bar? I would like it to just root itself to the bottom of the body. http://jsfiddle.net/LMHgM/4/

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is collapsing to fit content, not expanding to fit the page. You can also put a wrapper div around the divs with `position: absolute` and `height:` & `width:` 100%

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LMHgM/2/

```css
.wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems the best solution is to use `display: table` to divide up the screen.

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}


.group {
    display: table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LMHgM/5/